# "NullPointerException: null" in play framework

Tags: java, mongodb, playframework, morphia

I am new to play framework and I have project with java in play framework connected to the mongoDB via MorphiaPlay. My problem is that I cannot add data. This is some of my code

```
public class Sign extends Controller{


    static Form<Group> groupForm = form(Group.class);

    public static Result index() throws Exception {
        // redirect to the "group Result
        return redirect(routes.Sign.group());
    }

    public static Result group() {
        return ok(views.html.sign.render(Group.all(), groupForm));  
    }

    public static Result newGroup() {
        Form<Group> filledForm = groupForm.bindFromRequest();
        if(filledForm.hasErrors()) {
            return badRequest(views.html.sign.render(Group.all(), filledForm));
        } else {
            Group.create(filledForm.get());
            return redirect(routes.Sign.group());  
        }
    }
    }




@Entity
public class Group {

@Id
public ObjectId id;
@Required
public String name;
public String email;
public String username;
public String password;

public static List<Group> all() {
    if (MorphiaObject.datastore != null) {
        return MorphiaObject.datastore.find(Group.class).asList();
    } else {
        return new ArrayList<Group>();
    }
}

public static void create(Group group) {
    MorphiaObject.datastore.save(group);
}
```

And the error is

```
Execution exception
```

[NullPointerException: null]
In C:\lo\app\models\Group.java at line 37.

```
public static void create(Group group) {
    MorphiaObject.datastore.save(group);
}
```

My morphiaObject class

```
package controllers;
```

public class MorphiaObject extends GlobalSettings{

```
static public Mongo mongo;

static public Morphia morphia;

static public Datastore datastore;

@Override
public void onStart(play.Application arg0) {
    super.beforeStart(arg0);
    Logger.debug("** onStart **"); 
    try {
        MorphiaObject.mongo = new Mongo("127.0.0.1", 27017);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    MorphiaObject.morphia = new Morphia();
    MorphiaObject.datastore = MorphiaObject.morphia.createDatastore(MorphiaObject.mongo, "project");
    MorphiaObject.datastore.ensureIndexes();   
    MorphiaObject.datastore.ensureCaps();  

    Logger.debug("** Morphia datastore: " + MorphiaObject.datastore.getDB());
```

}
}

Can you please help!

Comment: My guess would be that `MorphiaObject.datastore` is not initialised. Note that you specifically check for it being null in the `all()` method. Could you show us the code where `MorphiaObject.datastore` is declared and initialised?

Comment: This is one a morphiaObject..                                  static public Datastore datastore;
 ...
 
  MorphiaObject.morphia = new Morphia();
  MorphiaObject.datastore = MorphiaObject.morphia.createDatastore(MorphiaObject.mongo, "project");
  MorphiaObject.datastore.ensureIndexes();   
  MorphiaObject.datastore.ensureCaps();  

  Logger.debug("** Morphia datastore: " + MorphiaObject.datastore.getDB());
}
}